# Calculate definite integral contains exponential and rational function

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, rational-functions

I need to solve a definite integral of exponential function combined with a rational function, which is depicted as follow:

$$I = \int\limits_{0}^\infty {\frac{{\exp \left( -t-\frac{1}{t} \right)}}{(1+t)^k}dt}$$
where k is a positive integer ($k \ge 1$). Can the integral $I$ be expressed in terms of special functions? (e.g. Bessel function, incomplete Gamma function, etc.).